# Crackling sound on 3.5 jack whenever I had a few seconds without playing sounds

Tags: debian, drivers, audio, parrotsec

**Symptoms**

---

Whenever I plug an audio jack into my PC a loud crackling can be heard in the headphones (tried 2 different pairs), it also happens whenever I play a sound if I didn't already have another audio playing in the last few seconds.

It is as if an audio service or card were putting itself to sleep after a few dozen seconds of inactivity and resuming it would cause a single crackling noise then the audio is clean again. A similar but much less agressive sound is heard a few seconds after an audio is done playing.

The crackling sound is much louder at its first instance (after boot) than any other time, it also happens whenever I plug in headphones or when the pc turns off.

**System**

---

I use a clean install of Parrot OS 5.0 (LTS) (debian based) on a stock HP ENVY PHOENIX 860-080nz 1.04(except for the storage), the issue was there from day one.

Here is the output of  cat /proc/asound/cards

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf320000 irq 129
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xdf080000 irq 17
 2 [AUDIO          ]: USB-Audio - USB  AUDIO
                      USB  AUDIO at usb-0000:00:14.0-7, full speed
```

Devices 0 and 1 use the snd_hda_intel driver which is native to the kernel, I didn't touch this.

Here is cropped output of lspci -v

```
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 High Definition Audio (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GM200 High Definition Audio
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
        Memory at df080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
[...]
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
        DeviceName: Onboard Audio
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 129
        Memory at df320000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at df300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

**Other tests I did**

---

USB speakers work perfectly fine.

This happens whether I am in headless mode or not (I suspected it might be KDE as the first crackling at boot comes during the KDE splash logo)

I dual boot with windows and have no such issues on the Windows side so I'm certain it's no hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer on another website, I had to comment out this line

> load-module module-suspend-on-idle

In the file /etc/pulse/default.pa then reboot.

To note that I had also switched to GNOME as I heard KDE has many sound issues but it made no difference. This fix now worked on both DEs